# Excel Macro to search if content of a column (filename) exists in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where I have the names of jpegs in columns F & G from rows 2 to 1800. I would like to use a macro in order to see if these Jpegs exist in a folder on my computer (mac) at a certain directory (ex. /user/Dropbox/Content/productinfo/pictures). If they do exist i would like to return the value "exists", if not, then "doesnt". The only issue is in a few cases no Jpeg exists in the spreadsheet so there is nothing to look up

I'm new to excel Macros. Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a user-defined function for that. In you case, you can call the below using:

```
=fileexists("C:\MyPath\"&f2)
```

Here's the function

```
Public Function FileExists(sPath As String)

If lcase(right(sPath,5)) <> ".jpeg" Then
    FileExists = ""
Else
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then
        FileExists = "Exists"
    Else
        FileExists = ""
    End If
End If


End Function
```

Comment: For the =fileexists("c:\mypath\"f2). I have the name of the file im searching for in columns F or G. How would i append that onto the end of the function? so it would read something linke =fileexists("/users/folder/pictures/1234/jpeg"&f2) where "1234.jpeg" is the value in the F column of that row

Comment: Yes. It checks if the path you submit exists (that's what the `Dir(spath)` part does: it returns the path if it's found or nothing if not.

Comment: You put the `Public function` part in a macro module and you use the formula in the excel worksheet as you would any other formula.

Comment: You shoudl replace `FileExists = "#VALUE!"` with `FileExists = CVErr(xlErrValue)` in order to actual return an excel error, not just a string.

Comment: Lauren, you want the string to reflect the path, so if 1234.jpeg is the filename you'd use `=fileexists("/users/folder/pictures/1234/jpeg/"&f2)`. If the file name is jpeg1234.jpeg, with only the 1234.jpeg in cell F2, then you'd use `=fileexists("/users/folder/pictures/1234/jpeg"&f2)`

Comment: Also if you edit a comment rather than add a new one, no notifications get issued, so you're less likely to get a prompt answer, or an answer at all.

Comment: if there is no value in the F cell for the row this is still returning exists. Why is that?

Comment: because it tells you that the folder exists, let me fix that in the function

Comment: im specifically looking for the file inside the folder. Not sure if i explained that correctly.ex. im looking if the contents of cell f2 ("1234.jpeg") exist in the folder. not sure if that clarifies or not

Comment: fixed the function, though it now only works for `.jpeg` extension files.

Comment: You can use the old version in the following structure `=if(len(f2)>0,fileexists("blablabla" & f2),"")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim iCount As Integer
iCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("F2:G1800"),".jpg")

if iCount > 0 Then

  'Do your checks
End If
```